# Error in my Decryptor/Encryptor Error CS0236

Tags: c#

> Error  CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

And I've been trying to fix it but I just can't
It is for an encryptor/decryptor program that I'm making

```
string hash = (materialSingleLineTextField4.Text);

private void materialRaisedButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Encrypt Function
    byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(materialSingleLineTextField1.Text);
    using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
        using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
        {
            ICryptoTransform transform = tripDes.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            materialSingleLineTextField2.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

My error is here `string hash = (materialSingleLineTextField4.Text);` 1st line and it underlines `materialSingleLineTestField4` in red
Can someone please help me? I'm having difficulites thanks c;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set this value outside the context of any method or event, at the class initialization level:

```
string hash = (materialSingleLineTextField4.Text);
```

But when the class is first being initialized this wouldn't make any sense.  There would be no value in `materialSingleLineTextField4.Text`, there isn't even guaranteed to be any valid instance of `materialSingleLineTextField4`.

If that value is to be set and used in the `materialRaisedButton1_Click` method then put that line of code in that method.  If needed, the *variable* can still be in a class-level scope.  But at the very least, setting it to the value of `materialSingleLineTextField4.Text` has to happen in a method or constructor.

Comment: or a constructor :)

Comment: @niceman: Good point, I've updated the answer.  I always think of the two as contextually similar enough, but it's certainly an important distinction.

Comment: Thanks c; This was really helpful for me